# C# HttpWebRequest response times out eventough works in browser

Tags: c#, visual-studio, timeout, httpwebrequest

I spent several hours debuging the code, playing with Fiddler and googling, but still no luck, so hopefully you will help me.

I am trying to get the source of http://www.finishline.com. The catch is, the HttpWebRequest works in some regions (like here in Slovakia), but doesn't work in USA what I need to achieve.

For USA the request.GetResponse() just time outs. I have tried countless headers combinations, but without success. Can you please help? Thank you

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.finishline.com");

            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36";
            request.AutomaticDecompression = (DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate);
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            request.Accept = " text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");                
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "sk,cs;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");

            var responseText = "";
            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                var httpWebResponse = response.GetResponseStream();

                using (var sr = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse))
                {
                    responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two kind of timeouts. Client timeout and server timeout. Have you tried doing something like this:

```
request.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
request.KeepAlive = true;
```

So, your GetResponse never get timedout you can check with it.

Or

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
{
var httpWebResponse = response.GetResponseStream();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse))
            {
                responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
}
```

Try this method to fix your issue.

Comment: nope, this didn't help. I just don't understand why it works from Europe and doesn't work from USA